# boto exception when using beeswithmachineguns with .pem

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

So I'm trying to use bees with machine guns to load test my own site.

```
01:01:11 Peters-MacBook-Pro:.ssh peterconerly$ bees up -k amazonkeypair -s 1 -g public -l ec2-user
Connecting to the hive.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/bees", line 5, in <module>
    main.main()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beeswithmachineguns/main.py", line 127, in main
    parse_options()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beeswithmachineguns/main.py", line 111, in parse_options
    bees.up(options.servers, options.group, options.zone, options.instance, options.login, options.key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beeswithmachineguns/bees.py", line 93, in up
    ec2_connection = boto.connect_ec2()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/__init__.py", line 135, in connect_ec2
    return EC2Connection(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 87, in __init__
    https_connection_factory, path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 638, in __init__
    debug, https_connection_factory, path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 281, in __init__
    host, config, self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/auth.py", line 308, in get_auth_handler
    'Check your credentials' % (len(names), str(names)))
boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['QuerySignatureV2AuthHandler'] Check your credentials
```

And I tried it directly with boto, as per http://www.synctus.com/blog/2010/04/securing-access-to-amazon-ec2-with-fingerprint-verification
:

```
>>> import boto.ec2
>>> conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('eu-west-1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/__init__.py", line 53, in connect_to_region
    for region in regions(**kw_params):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/__init__.py", line 38, in regions
    c = EC2Connection(**kw_params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 87, in __init__
    https_connection_factory, path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 638, in __init__
    debug, https_connection_factory, path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 281, in __init__
    host, config, self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/auth.py", line 308, in get_auth_handler
    'Check your credentials' % (len(names), str(names)))
boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['QuerySignatureV2AuthHandler'] Check your credentials
>>>
```

Comment: poor baby was sleep deprived.  All of the answers I googled for this question were about AWS secret keys, not using boto with a pem file.  And it was failing immediately, before I even offered it credentials-- if you look at the python interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message suggests, boto is unable to find any credentials to use.  It looks in the following places:

- You can pass them explicitly as `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` when calling connect_to_region
- You can set the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`
- You can create a boto config file (see [this](http://code.google.com/p/boto/wiki/BotoConfig) for details) and place that file in either `/etc/config` or `~/.boto` or you can put it wherever you want and set the environment variable `BOTO_CONFIG` to point to it.
- If you are using [IAM Roles](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/06/iam-roles-for-ec2-instances-simplified-secure-access-to-aws-service-apis-from-ec2.html) boto will find the credentials in the instance metadata on the EC2 server.

Comment: Thanks garnaat-- but I'm trying to use boto with a .pem file, not with the accesskeyid/secretaccesskey combination.  Additionally in the python interpreter boto fails on the step BEFORE it needs credentials.

Comment: @Civilian - Regarding the latter: As the error message suggests, calling `boto.ec2.connect_to_region()` requires credentials already (as one would expect actually); how do you figure it fails on the step _before_ it needs credentials (in fact there is none but the innocent `import boto.ec2` statement)?

Comment: @Civilian - Regarding the former: Using the AWS command line tools with the legacy certificate/key authentication scheme is deprecated already and will be removed at some point; please consider switching to the meanwhile ubiquitous `access key ID`/`secret access key` approach - your life will be much easier (and more secure if used in combination with [AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/)).

Comment: Boto does not support SOAP so, therefore, does not support authentication via certificate files.  You have to use an access_key/secret_key combination with boto.

Comment: Also, connect_to_region, for the EC2 connection object does require credentials because it calls the DescribeRegions request to get a list of the currently supported regions for the EC2 service.